# How to get the userprofile properties based on Author (created by )

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile, user-profile-property

I need to show the User profile Picture, Department, and location for every individual user who is Creating or adding the document to the library.  I think we need to get the properties based on Authors name?  I tried, but I got only current user Properties. please suggest me some idea to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below using REST API:

```
var accountName = 'domain\user';
$.ajax({
        url: "https://sitecollectionurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);                 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
});
```

If you are using JSOM, try below code:

```
var personProperties;

SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
   // Make sure PeopleManager is available 
   SP.SOD.executeFunc('userprofile', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', function() {   
        getUserProperties();
   });

});

function getUserProperties() {

    // Replace the placeholder value with the target user's credentials.
    var targetUser = "domainName\\userName";

    // Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    // Get user properties for the target user.
    // To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the
    // getMyProperties method.
    personProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(targetUser);

    // Load the PersonProperties object and send the request.
    clientContext.load(personProperties);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds.
function onRequestSuccess() {
        console.log(personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Department']);    
}

// This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I hope above script is for getting the Current user Profile properties right?  But I need to get User profile properties based on Created by column

Comment: `var targetUser = "domainName\\userName";`  or `accountName='domain\user'`, here you can pass the author name. So, whatever is the user you pass in these variables, the properties of that account will be fetched.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following rest api URL to get required properties

**Get all properties of Specific User:**

For Office 365/SharePoint Online:
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|loginname@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com'

For SharePoint 2013 On-Premise:
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='domain\username'

**Get Specific UserProfile Property of Specific User:**

For Office 365/SharePoint Online:
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='LastName')?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|loginname@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com'

For SharePoint 2013 On-Premise:
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='LastName')?@v='domain\username'